# What's wrong with this binary search?

Tags: java, search, binary-search

```
public static int binsrch (int[] a, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length - 1;

    while (true) { 
        if (low > high) return -(low+1); 
        int mid = (low + high)/2; 
        if      (a[mid] < key)  low = mid + 1;
        else if (a[mid] > key) high = mid - 1;
        else    return mid;
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: If you find it totally alright, what's the problem?

Comment: @codeMan Why not?

Comment: don't you think you should be returning a[mid]?

Comment: because every time a loop is execute a new memory location is allocated, which is not necessary and it may be true that we will loose that value store in it in the previous iteration

Comment: One thing that's definitely wrong is that it does not compile (check the condition in the `else if`)

Comment: Change `(a[mid] > key])` to `(a[mid] > key)`.

Comment: `else if (a[mid] > key])` is wrong

Comment: @codeMan That's a misunderstanding on your part: the loop reuses the same memory location. Declaring `mid` outside the loop would have been wrong.

Comment: really? Enlighten me please... I dint know that.

Comment: ah.. @dasblinkenligh is right... I looked around and I found that it does not matter! Compile works its **magic**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two, possibly three, things I can see wrong with it.

It uses `(low + high)/2`. The addition may overflow to a negative number if the array is very large. If so, division by 2 will lead to a negative index. This can be fixed by using `(low + high)>>>1`.

It is not documented. I am guessing that it is intended to return the match index if it finds the key in the array, and a negative value on miss. I am not sure exactly what the negative result is supposed to represent, due to the lack of documentation.

Depending on the missing specification, there may be additional problems.